# How to allow ajax server side record deletion with data tables

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, coffeescript, datatables

I am using datatables to model my users data and wish to allow for the deletion of a record in the database at the same time as the removal from the view when the user clicks the button called 'Delete Restaurant'. From the datatables site, the removal just hides the record form the user, not actually deleting anything in the datacase:https://datatables.net/examples/api/select_single_row.html

**How can I call ajax in locations.js.coffee to delete the selected table record record from the database?**

manage.html.erb, the table to select a location and then delete it (within the Locations views):

```
<%<button id="deleteRestaurant">Delete Restaurant</button> %>
    <table id="restaurantLocations" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Store Number</th>
            <th>Address</th>
            <th>City</th>
            <th>State</th>
            <th>Zip Code</th>
        <th>Major City Bidding</th>
            <th>Sit Down?</th>
            <th>Drive Through?</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tfoot id="input">
        <th>Store Number</th>
        <th>Address</th>
        <th>City</th>
        <th>State</th>
        <th>Zip Code</th>
        <th>Major City Bidding</th>
        <th>Sit Down?</th>
        <th>Drive Through?</th>
      </tr>
    </tfoot>
    <%# current_user.locations.each do |branch| %>
    <tbody>
      <% @restaurant.locations.each do |branch| %>
            <tr>
                <td><%= branch.store_number %></td>
                <td><%= branch.address %></td>
                <td><%= branch.city_name %></td>
                <td><%= branch.state.upcase %></td>
                <td><%= branch.zip %></td>
          <td><%= City.where(id: branch.city_id).pluck(:city).first %></td>
                <td><%= branch.sit_down %></td>
                <td><%= branch.drive_through %></td>
            </tr>
        <% end %>
    </tbody>
    </table>
```

locations.js.coffee (right now it only 'removes'/hides the record):

```
table = $("#restaurantLocations").DataTable()

  $("#deleteRestaurant").click ->
    table.row(".selected").remove().draw false
    $.ajax({
      url: "/uploadlocations/",
      type: "post",
      dataType: "json",
      data: {"_method":"delete"}
    });

    return

  return
```

Comment: there is no event handling code shown for the delete button, so error shown is coming from different code than what is posted

Comment: That error is distracting from the question at hand, I removed it. How can I setup ajax to remove those records that were selected by datatables select?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To delete multiple rows you would first need to determine what specific data would be needed to create the proper db query.

Following assumes that `store_number` will suffice for now and it will be pulled from the cell text. You can use the datatables rendering methods for more customization such as using `data-` attributes

Loop through all the `selected` class and make a request for each one and then remove the row

```
$('#deleteRestaurant').click(function () {
    $('tr.selected').each(function () {
        var $row = $(this);
        var store = $row.find('td:first').text();
        $.post('path/to/server', {store_id: store}, function (response) {
            if ( /* validation of response*/ ) {
                table.row($row).remove();
            }
        });
    });

    table.draw();
});
```

If you need a more specific identifier for your back end code you could always put it into a hidden column

Comment: What you posted is what I already have, but you have it in javascript. Your code simply `.removes` the row from the table and does nothing to the underlying data.  What I need is the way to include `$.ajax` syntax to literally delete the record from the database, not simply 'remove' aka hide it from the table

Comment: so you need to receive the posted data the same way you do a form in endpoint defined by url you use,  process it to do the deletion and send back something to validate in client. If you were wanting server code I'm not sure why you posted all the client side code in your question

Comment: I updated the question with the method I am trying but have yet to get working. I am calling $.ajax, but cannot get the delete to work

Comment: you need to have some identifier as to what to delete. And don't remove the row without success validation from server

Comment: In my code it's `table.row(".selected")` to choose what to delete, how can I trace that back to the specific id in the database of that record entry?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63820/discussion-between-sauron-and-charlietfl).

Comment: What is the path to server?